# How to form a Java Regex to split string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking for a Java Regex, so that I can break the following expresion :
first using '-', but if '-' is used in a quotation mark it shoul be ignored.

e.g: a test - which "contains "-""  inside - a quotation mark.
result should be an arry like this:

```
[0]: a test 
[1]: which "contains "-""  inside
[2]: a quotation mark
```

I am not really good with regular expression and will be thank full if anyone can help me :)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Regex Planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/) to test out any regex's you make

You should be able to achieve this with

```
String[] splitAray = yourString.Split("[^\"]-[^\"]")
```

Update using look ahead/behind so that the characters before and after - are not consumed

```
String[] splitAray = yourString.Split("(?!\")-(?!\")")
```

Comment: I'd make those a lookbehind and lookahead, just so the thing matched is exactly the dash, rather than including pieces of whatever happens to be on either side.

Comment: -1 This will consume the characters either side if the dash, which makes this answer essentially "wrong"

Comment: Yeah, this will eat the quotes. (The output will be [a test ,  which "contains - inside ,  a quotation mark])

Comment: @Jiri It wouldnt have eaten the quotes, it would have eaten the spaces

Answer (score 2):

Solution using lookbehind and lookahead:

```
String input = "a test - which \"contains \"-\" inside - a quotation mark";
String[] chunks = input.split("(?<!\")-(?!\")");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chunks));
```

OUTPUT:

```
[a test ,  which "contains "-" inside ,  a quotation mark]
```

EDIT: changing the first part of regexp (`(?!\")`) to `(?<!\")`

Comment: The first part needs to be a lookbehind, or it'll match the dash rather than the can't-be-a-quote before.

Comment: I dont think that your edit `(?<!\")` is correct, consider the input `"some text"-more text` this would not split at the `-`